# isActive lib cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, flux, redux

i am building an app that uses react-router,flux and i found this library called redux-auth(https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth). I am trying to use it since it has a lot of work done regarding loging,sign up, etc. 
I installed the dependencies with npm in this order - >

`npm install redux-auth --save`

`npm install material-ui --save`

`npm install react-tap-event-plugin`

After this i got the error i mention, the module isActive cannot be found.
So i searched the web and found this post: 
https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/issues/111

Where they fix it with this command: `npm install --save history react-router@latest followed by npm install --save redux-router@1.0.0-beta3`

After this my app broke, and now i get the error : `"Error: ajax not supported in this browser" when prerendering Router with / and {}`

The line with such error: `<%= react_router 'Router', 'HistoryLocation', {}, { prerender: params[:noprerender].nil?, prerender_location: root_path } %>`

Tried uninstalling such libraries but didn't work out, tried removing the node_modules dir and rebuilding with npm but didn't work. 
Any help or advice? is impossible for me to use this library? is it maybe a compability problem between flux and redux? Any help is welcome.

Edit #1 : I am using Chrome.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Redux is an implementation of Flux actually. You shouldn't use redux-auth if you aren't using redux already.

Comment: Hello atanas, thanks for your comment, so you say the problem is that i am not using redux, this means that the libraries have no compability? should i look for something else? any more info on this regard?